# Property in service not updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Having a little trouble with my `authentication` service. I basically have this on my service:

```js
angular.factory('authentication', [..., function() {
    var currentUser = {};

    return {
        login: function() {
            currentUser = { username: 'Foo' };
        },
        logout: function() {
            currentUser = {};
        }
        user: currentUser;
    }
})]
```

And in my `AppCtrl`, I have this:

```js
 angular.module('App').controller('AppCtrl', [..., function() {
     $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
         console.log(authentication.user);
     });
 }]);
```

In my `LogoutCtrl`, I have this:

```js
 angular.controller('LogoutCtrl', [..., function() {
     authentication.logout();
     $state.go('login');
 }]);
```

Once the state changes to `login`, the console still prints `username: 'Foo'`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried applying $scope.$apply()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make the first assignment in the object you are referring to the reference of the user. You then replace that reference when you call logout() so your old user, bound earlier, is unchanged. Change it to a getter function instead:

```
...
getUser: function() {
    return user; // always the correct reference
}
```

Now call that in the console.log and it will work

Comment: `getUser: function() { return currentUser; }` seem to have done the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.factory('authentication', [..., function() {
    var currentUser = {};

    return {
        login: function() {
            currentUser = { username: 'Foo' };
        },
        logout: function() {
            currentUser = {};
        }
        user: currentUser;
    }
})]
```

Your login/logout methods change the value of the variable `currentUser`. These changes are not propagated to the `authentication.property`.

Two possible fixes:

1) Use `this.user` instead of `var currentUser`:

```
angular.factory('authentication', [..., function() {
    return {
        login: function() {
            this.user = { username: 'Foo' };
        },
        logout: function() {
            this.user = {};
        }
        user: {};
    }
})]
```

2) Implement `user` as a getter-based property:

```
angular.factory('authentication', [..., function() {
    var currentUser = {};

    var auth = {
        login: function() {
            currentUser = { username: 'Foo' };
        },
        logout: function() {
            currentUser = {};
        }
    };

    Object.defineProperty(auth, 'user', {
        get: function() { return currentUser; }
    });

    return svc;
})]
```